# `[a, b] + [c, d]` or append or extend, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, extend

I have seen somebody using `[a, b] + [c, d]` where i would have expected to use `[a,b].extend([c,d])` or the use of `append`.

logically, it looks cleaner to use the `+` sign as opposed to a function (even if built-in).

I have looked into this and see comparisons between `append` and `extend`, but the limited mention of merely using the `+` sign.

Can someone explain what might be a convention or best practice (if there is one) or if there are differences in what they are?

Comment: Well, in the case of `[a, b] + [c, d]`, you are taking two lists, concatenating them, and creating a new list in the process. `extend` and `append` modify the list in-place.

Comment: I also see that `extend` behaves like `+=` in the associated similar questions which could be recursive (if calling itself) whereas `+` is not recursive.